# Slack bot - events api, I wanted to get trigger_id so I can create modal

Tags: slack-api

My requirement is to "display modal in slack app" and I need trigger_id for the same.
Basically I wanted to display modal, when quote or Purchse order is approved.
To display modal, I need trigger_id.
I will not be using "shortcuts feature" or "command" , so I wanted to use events subscription on the bot.
So I am looking for bot event, to which bot can subscribe and get trigger_id in request payload.

Can someone suggest, which bot event should I subscribe - so I can get trigger_id?

Thank you
Divyesh

Answer (score 0):

Overall, Slack won't let apps or integrations open modals that don't derive from a direct human user interaction on Slack. This way, users don't unexpectedly have dialogs or windows opened in their client without first invoking it by clicking a button, running a command, or executing a shortcut with intent and (at least some) expectation of what comes next.

There are no ways to get a valid `trigger_id` without the user first taking action in Slack.